# Switching test::unit with rspec under rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove unit test and replace it with rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072662/how-to-remove-unit-test-and-replace-it-with-rspec)

Kinda odd question here: when you go with rpsec instead of test::unit on rails, what do you do with the test dir? Keep it (for any compatibility issues maybe?) or remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always kept it, in case some plugin or generator expects to find it there.

If you don't like having the test directory, I suggest you try to remove it and see if it works. You can always recreate it later, if you notice that you need it.