# How to remove unit test and replace it with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a rails app, that is setup with the default test unit, how can I remove it and use rspec instead?  (I don't have any tests written, I just didn't ignore it during app generation).

Comment: AFAIK, they can work together you are not obliged to remove the default test unit within rails to use rspec.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915534/rails-3-if-im-using-rspec-can-i-just-delete-the-test-folder

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can actually have any number of testing frameworks in use at the same time. For example, you can use cucumber, rspec, test-unit and mini-test and they will all function without stepping on each other's feet. To use rspec in rails simply add the following to your Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

Then update or install your bundle and run the following command to setup rspec:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails).

Answer (score 13):

For Rails 3, to really remove test_unit from your application, you need to remove (or comment out) the test_unit [Railtie](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Railtie) in `application.rb`

```
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

As Pan mentions, you don't have to just choose one testing framework. But you asked how to remove test_unit, so that is how you really do it.

(Curious about what this line of code does? Check out the [railties/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb).)

To install RSpec into your app, follow the [directions on rspec-rails](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/). As it says, add rspec-rails to the :test and :development groups in the Gemfile:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
end
```

Then run `bundle install` and then `rails generate rspec:install`

Comment: I got the pointer to remove the Railtie from https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2564 because it gets rid of the default `rake test` tasks. But I'm not seeing the test_unit Railtie in a current Rails app -- looks like something is different now.