# Remove test::unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I forgot to create my application with the -T argument and now it's installed with test::unit. How do I remove test::unit and stop it from creating tests for each controller / model generated, after I have already created the application? Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your config/application.rb try

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec #=> or whatever
end
```

**In response to comment**

Try

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework nil
end
```

May not be the "most appropriate" or Rails-ish way, but it works

**Update**

I was reading the Rails Initialization Guide today and realized that the most likely reason Test::Unit is still being included is this line:

`require 'rails/all'`

Which could be replaced with:

```
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
```

This should take care of the issue. If you're using Rails 3.1.x you'd also include

```
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

if you're planning on using the asset pipeline.

**Update 2**

For Rails 3.2 you should use this:

```
config.app_generators do |c|
  c.test_framework :rspec, :fixture => true,
                           :fixture_replacement => nil

  c.integration_tool :rspec
  c.performance_tool :rspec
end
```

Answer (score 8):

To remove Test:Unit in Rails 4:

Replace the following line from **config/application.rb**:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

With:

```
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

You can safely remove the test directory as well.

Answer (score 7):

Build a new application with `rails new APP_NAME --skip-test-unit` in **Rails 4** results in:

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Answer (score 7):

On Rails 5.1 and Rails 5.2

in `config/application.rb`

remove or comment out

```
require 'rails/all'
```

and then include

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Also if you do not wish to generate system test files add the following:

```
# Don't generate system test files.
config.generators.system_tests = nil
```

Once this is done, you can delete the `test` directory

Comment: Yes, but now with 5.2 you might also add: `require "active_storage/engine"`

Answer (score 6):

On `Rails 6` in `config/application.rb` replace

```rb
require 'rails/all'
```

For:

```rb
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_mailbox/engine"
require "action_text/engine"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Add `config.generators.system_tests = nil` to the Application block like this:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    ...

    # Don't generate system test files.
    config.generators.system_tests = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way, as I mention in a similar [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172652/109618) is to do this...

For Rails 3, to remove test_unit from your application, you need to remove (or comment out) the test_unit Railtie in `config/application.rb`:

```
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

If you are curious about what this line of code does, check out the [railties/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb) which currently looks like this:

```
module Rails
  class TestUnitRailtie < Rails::Railtie
    config.app_generators do |c|
      c.test_framework :test_unit, :fixture => true,
                                   :fixture_replacement => nil

      c.integration_tool :test_unit
      c.performance_tool :test_unit
    end

    rake_tasks do
      load "rails/test_unit/testing.rake"
    end
  end
end
```