# Should I delete the Rails "test" folder if I'm not using Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just finished an online course on RSpec and I like it a lot better than the test library that Rails comes with by default (Test::Unit). I looked in the "test" folder and all it really contains is Test::Unit testing code. Is it safe to delete if I'm planning to use only RSpec for my application?

Comment: maybe it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072662/how-to-remove-unit-test-and-replace-it-with-rspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is safe to delete the Test folder. Infact, when adding in Guard and Spork the server attempts to load the Test::Unit framework as well and generates a timeout error. Deleting the folder prevents this from happening. There are other ways to stop Guard and Spork from doing this, but I found this to be the easiest.

Comment: Which other folders can I delete for production? `tmp`? `vendor`?